# Place my own controls overlapping Google visualization chart

Tags: google-visualization, paging

I'd like to add paging controls to my Google Visualization bar chart, similar to the one described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/dxNifFZNJbQ) (keywords: thenez101 Google Visualization BarChart Paging), but instead of flowing my paging controls around the Google bar chart, I'd like to place them on top of the chart. When I place my controls inside the chart's div, however, I see them only until the chart is drawn.

Assigning my controls a CSS class whose z-index property I have changed to positive and negative has not worked. Perhaps I can change their z position after my ready event has fired? Has anyone succeeded in getting this working?

Thanks, BH

Comment: Please post some sample code so that we can use that as a base, a quick diagram of what you are trying to accomplish would also be useful...